# Replacing math equations by result

Tags: bash, awk, sed, regular-expression, math

What is the best way to replace, in a file, equations found using some predefined regex with the result.

Let's say each equation formula is compatible with `bc -l` (basic calculator with float numbers handling).

For example, saying equations are delimited by `[[` and `]]` (just as an example):

Input would be:

```
Results show that each unit should generate
approx. [[7*9/2.0]]Wh per day.
All the same ...
```

Desired output:

```
Results show that each unit should generate
approx. 31.5Wh per day.
All the same ...
```

My best try:

```
while read line; do
    
    if [[ $line =~ \[\[.*\]\] ]]; then
    
        equ=`echo "$line" | sed "s|.*\[\[||" | sed "s|]].*||"`
        res=`echo "$equ" | bc -l | awk '{print $1+0}'`
        
        new_line=`echo $line | sed "s|\[\[.*]]|$res|"`
        
        echo $new_line
        
    else
        
        echo $line
        
    fi

done < $infile
```

Output:

```
Results show that each unit should generate
approx. 31.5Wh per day.
All the same ...
```

But wonder if there would not be a simpler way (without the while loop).

In addition, this will work if there is only one equation per line.

Comment: What defines an "equation"? Will they always be in double parentheses? Can you or can you not have more than one per line? Can you have more than double parentheses? Things like `(((7*9/2.0) -1)*12)`? Can you have negative expressions like `-((1+2))`?

Comment: Oh, here the double parentheses is just a random way to define equations. It could be @7*9/2.0@ or [7*9/2.0] or whatever. The double parenthesis was just inspired from the $(()) in bash. (The input file layout is not fixed. It's just an example and can be changed w/o issue.) Let's say the content of the equation is compatible with "bc -l".

Comment: So how can we know what to do? Please [edit] your question and clarify what you need.

Comment: Should the expression be evaluated using integer arithmetic or floating point arithmetic? If floating point, how many decimals do you need in the resulting number? If the "markup" may be changed, is there anything stopping you from using `$((...))` if the shell that interprets it knows about floating point arithmetic evaluates it, or will you also be using _functions_ like `sqrt()` and `sin()` etc.?  If one wants to be picky: You also mentioned _equations_, but actually only show _expressions_...

Comment: Changed the delimiter in the question to avoid confusion about parentheses. Edited as well to precise what the equation could contain. Simply, let's say it's compatible with "bc -l". So, the length of equation is unknown (can be a single number or many characters). Sqrt, sin etc. would be wonderful, but beyond my needs. In my script try I use awk just to polish the output format (avoid things like 31.500000000). This is a plus, not a requirement.

Comment: @taalf, `bc -l` does add a bunch of stuff over numbers and `+-*/`, namely functions like `sqrt(x)` and `s(x)` (sin), but also variables.

Comment: @ilkkachu Cool :-) Thanks for the info (so far always switched to awk for such things)

Comment: copy/paste your code info http://shellcheck.net

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Compatible with `bc -l`, you say? I guess your best bet is to run `bc -l`, then. You can do that pretty easily with Perl. If we have `math.txt` like so:

```
two times [[3*7]] is [[2*3*7]]
[[scale=6; a=4; a*s(3.141/4)]]
```

This would scan through it and pass the blocks within `[[...]]` through `bc -l`:

```bash
$ perl -pe 's,\[\[(.*?)\]\], $a=qx/echo "$1" | bc -l /; chomp $a; $a ,ge' math.txt 
two times 21 is 42
2.828008
```

It just captures what ever is between `[[` and `]]`, shoves it as input to `bc -l`, and replaces the bracketed block with the output.

Note that this does run a new instance of `bc` for each block, so variable assignments won't keep between blocks. (But you can set the `scale` per-block, as I did above.) The match is non-greedy, so that
multiple blocks per line work, but it does mean the end separator can't appear as part of the expression, which is why I used `]]`.
(With parens, there could be a clash: e.g. `((3*(a+(b+c))))` would fail, and you'd need to separate the parens with spaces, like`((3*(a+(b+c) ) ))` instead.)

Brackets are still special in regexes, so they're matched with `\[\[` and `\]\]`; the parens in the regex are for capturing the inner part. There might be better ways to deal with the newline that `bc` prints,  though.

Launching a new process for each arithmetic block seems a bit heavy, but it makes for a rather trivial solution.

**Note that this is unsafe with hostile inputs!** As the contents of the block are passed through the shell to be fed for `bc`, any shell syntax in the arithmetic expression would be processed. E.g. this would run the `uname` command:

```
[[ $(uname -a >&2 ) ]]
```

That could be fixed by opening a pipe to `bc` from Perl, but it might not fit into a one-liner then.

Comment: Yeees ! Thanks ! :)
Not familiar with perl yet.
Just added '| awk "{print $1+0}"' after 'bc -l' to remove ugly number format issue.

Comment: @taalf use this instead, `perl -pe 's,\[\[(.*?)\]\], $a=qx/echo "$1" | bc -l/ +0; $a ,ge'` and you can avoid the call to `awk`. But it does pass the result of the arithmetic expression back into `perl` as a number, which may mean you lose precision on large values.

Comment: @taalf, strike what I wrote before, that's not safe for untrusted input as the way I did it, the arithmetic expression gets passed through and processed by a shell. So take care with that.

Answer (score 0):

Using any awk:

```
$ cat tst.awk
{
    while ( match($0,/\[\[.*]]/) ) {
        $0 = substr($0,1,RSTART-1) eval(substr($0,RSTART+2,RLENGTH-4)) substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)
    }
    print
}

function eval(equation,      cmd,line,rslt) {
    rslt = "FAILED:" equation
    if ( equation !~ /[\047"]|system/ ) {
        cmd = "awk \047BEGIN{print " equation "; exit}\047"
        if ( (cmd | getline line) > 0 ) {
            rslt = line+0
        }
        close(cmd)
    }
    return rslt
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
Results show that each unit should generate
approx. 31.5Wh per day.
All the same ...
```

I'm calling `awk` again instead of `bc` to do the math part since while we hope `bc` would exist (it didn't on my cygwin install), we **know** that `awk` does as we're already calling it.

That will be slow, though, as it's spawning a subshell every time to do the `eval`.

Answer (score 0):

Your sample expression looks like it can be evaluated by `perl` directly, in which case you can avoid having to invoke `bc` for each with something like:

```bash
perl -pe 's{\[\[([\d\s./*+-]+)\]\]}{eval$1}ge' < "$infile"
```

Here only processing expressions containing digits, whitespace and `./*+-` to avoid introducing command injection vulnerabilities.

It's also compatible with `zsh`'s arithmetic expressions, so if switching from bash to zsh is an option, that could be done with:

```bash
set -o extendedglob
print -r -- ${"$(<$infile)"//(#b)\[\[([[:digit:][:space:].\/*+-]##)\]\]/$((match[1]))}
```

You could also get `bc -l` to do the computation there with:

```bash
set -o extendedglob
print -r -- ${"$(<$infile)"//(#b)\[\[([[:digit:][:space:].\/*+-]##)\]\]/$(bc -l <<<$match[1])}
```